# Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation

I have problem with my program I don't know what to do :(

```
double spocitaj(FILE *fr,double **polsum, int *cena){

int r=0, i=0,k=0;
double n=0;
char c;


while((c=getc(fr))!=EOF){
    if(c=='\n') r++;
    if(r==4){
        *cena=k++;
        r=5;
    }
    if(r==6) r=0;       
}

*polsum=(double *)calloc(k,sizeof(double));
r=1;
rewind(fr);

while((c=getc(fr))!=EOF){

    if(c=='\n') r++;
    if(r==4) {
                    ungetc(c,fr);
            fscanf(fr,"%lf", &n);
            *polsum[i]=n;
            i++;
    }
    if(r==6) r=1;       
}

for(i=0;i<*cena;i++)
                    printf("%.2lf\n", *polsum[i]);
return 0;
```

}

Can you help me please?
this is a message:
Unhandled exception at `0x012947F8` in Projekt 1.exe: `0xC0000005`:

> Access violation writing location `0xCCCCCCCC`.

Comment: Probably an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: How can I fix this? pls ....

Comment: Run in the debugger and find the line that throws the exception, then examine the values and compare to what you expect.

Comment: In main function I have : ...double *polsum; and then I call function spocitaj(fr,&polsum, &cena);

Comment: I'd hate to be the person who has to update/maintain your code!

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC is uninitialized memory [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 5):

`*polsum[i]=n;` should be `(*polsum)[i] = n;`.

`*polsum[i]` is `*(polsum[i])`, which treats `polsum` as an array, but you likely intend it to be a single pointer, a pointer to where there is a `double *`.

Changing this to `(*polsum)[i])` says "Look up the `double *` that is where `polsum` points. That `double *` points to a place where there are many `double` objects. Get the `i`<sup>th</sup> one.”